# How to set a "Tag" with an "Id" to a TextView in a xml file?

Tags: java, android

How to add a "tag" with an "id" to a TextView in an xml file so that it can be retrieved using `myTextView.getTag(R.id.MY_TAG)`

Answer (score 0):

In API >= 21 You can define it as next:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/your_view_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World">

    <tag android:id="@+id/your_tag_id" android:value="YourTagValue" />

</TextView>
```